# How to visualize a set of many optimizations of posterior simulations of an objective function?

Tags: data-visualization, optimization, posterior

I started by fitting a model:  $y = f(X) + \epsilon$.  The model includes random effects and coefficients -- there is a lot of heterogeneity in the population (and the data is longitudinal).  I then took 1000 draws of $\beta|data \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta,V_\beta)$.  (I represented the random effects as penalized fixed effects, so that I could more easily take a draw from the parameter covariance matrix).  For each of the 1000 draws, I calculated $y_{max} = argmax_X\left(g(f(X),R)\right)$, subject to various individual-level constraints that varied by the observation, and $R$, which I specify as a gradient from 0:20.  (R is a price, I want to see how optimal choices change given price R for actors with heterogeneous circumstances).

I now have a Nx1000x20 set of optimized values of $X$, and corresponding $y_{max}$ values.  N is about 300.  I want to plot $y_{max}$ as a function of $R$, capturing both between-individual heterogeneity as well as within-individual uncertainty.

But it seems like too much information to visualize effectively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your longitudinal component is here. Or what is the 300, assuming the 300 is individuals, you could make the plots for samples of individuals. And then repeatedly sample several times to get a sense of the individual to individual variability. You could do this in most any graphing package, eg R, ggplot2.

There is a short video at this site [https://vimeo.com/65846792][1] that illustrates how I looked at longitudinal data set on about 900 individuals, with various statistics calculated on the values of each subject.

[1]: https://vimeo.com/65846792 Video showing exploration of longitudinal data using ggobi

Comment: I've got 300 individuals.  For each individual, I take 1000 draws from the distribution of $\beta$.  I take those betas and drop them into an objective function, which I maximize.  Thus, for each 300 IDs, I've got 1000 versions of $y = f(R)$.  This is 300,000 lines on a plot, or 300 lines on a plot with confidence intervals around them (defined by empirical quantiles).

Comment: Or 300 separate plots, containing lines, with confidence intervals, that you animate through. You could look at the animations package in R. Doesn't seem so difficult.